# Why my spark dataframe has only 1 partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark= SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").getOrCreate() 
df = spark.read.csv("annual-enterprise-survey-2021-financial-year-provisional-size-bands-csv.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
sqldf = spark.sql('SELECT _c5 FROM table WHERE  _c5 > "1000"')
print(sqldf.count())
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
print(sqldf.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

I am trying to see the effect of parallelism in spark. How can I decide how many partitions will I have when I am running actions on my dataframe? In the below code, my output for number of partitions is 1s. In UI it shows 1 task for the count job. Shouldnt spark create 4 tasks(number of cores on my local machine) and then do the count operation faster?

Answer (score 0):

Partitions and workers are not mapped one to one although they can be.

`local[4]` defines the number of workers. To specify number of partitions for a dataframe, one can use [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html) or coallece function.

For example you can write

`sqldf = sqldf.repartition(4)`

Comment: I thought spark handles this. Isn't it more logical to use 4 partitions for a count() job? Why I need to do this manually?

Comment: Default number of partitions that spark will create is mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-performance-tuning.html). However, number of partitions depends on hardware and other configuration. In your case